# Apple SeismicXML Example App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

In the SeismicXMLAppDelegate implementation file of this class they have the following code:

```
// forward declarations

@interface SeismicXMLAppDelegate ()



@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURLConnection *earthquakeFeedConnection;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *earthquakeData;    // the data returned from the NSURLConnection

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSOperationQueue *parseQueue;     // the queue that manages our NSOperation for parsing earthquake data



- (void)addEarthquakesToList:(NSArray *)earthquakes;

- (void)handleError:(NSError *)error;

@end
```

Why do they have a second interface in the implementation file?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SeismicXML/Listings/Classes_SeismicXMLAppDelegate_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007323-Classes_SeismicXMLAppDelegate_m-DontLinkElementID_10

Answer (score 2):

This is a called an Extension (or an anonymous Category) in Objective-C

You can add properties, change its attributes and declare new methods like in that example.
Why not doing it in the interface file?
Well there could be a lot of reasons, for design purposes, for not to exposing some properties., etc.

For example, you cannot call `myAppDelegate.earthquakeData` from `RootViewController.m` even if you `#import "SeismicXMLAppDelegate.h"`.
You can only access to `earthquakeData`property from inside of `SeismicXMLAppDelegate` class.

You can read more about Categories and Extensions here: [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1)